# JQuery interferes with getting scroll position in Android browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll-position

I previously posted a question explaining how every method of **getting Y scroll position in Javascript on Android browsers was typically returning zero**, or some significantly wrong low number. Literally every possible way of getting Y scroll position that I found was broken.

I've since established that **it was only happening when I included jQuery**. It seems to completely break the functionality.

**Is this a known bug? Is there a fix?** I'd look at trying to fix the bug in jQuery but that would be way too advanced for my abilities.

I'm just amazed that such a widespread framework would produce such a disastrous bug in such a large proportion of browsers without being rapidly fixed.

It would affect anyone trying to do any common technique like dynamic loading on scrolling, animations on scrolling, etc etc etc

Edit: I see a close vote for lacking clarity or detail. Could someone please enlighten me as to what clarity or detail is missing? In my opinion this is crystal clear if you've ever used javascript to determine scroll position.